# How to prove A ⊆ B ⇒ C \ B ⊆ C \ A

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How to prove this implication?

A ⊆ B ⇒ C \ B ⊆ C \ A

my try:

if  A ⊆ B ⇒ x ∈ A ∧ x ∈ B

if C \ B ⊆ C \ A ⇒ if x ∈ (C \ A) then (x ∈ C ∧ x ∉ A ∧ if x ∈ (C \ B) then x ∈ C ∧ x ∉ B

Can't see where to go from here

Comment: You want to prove that $x\in C\setminus B\Rightarrow x\in C\setminus A$. Now, $x\in C\setminus B$ means that  (1) $x\in C$ and (2) $x\not\in B$. Since $A\subseteq B$, (2) implies that (3) $x\not\in A$. From (1) and (3) you get that $x\in C\setminus A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be more careful. You write

> if $A ⊆ B ⇒ x ∈ A ∧ x ∈ B$

which is, sorry to have to say it, nonsense.

By definition, $A\subseteq B$ *means the same as* “for all $x$, if $x\in A$, then $x\in B$”.

By definition, $C\setminus B\subseteq C\setminus A$ *means the same as* “for all $x$, if $x\in C\setminus B$, then $x\in C\setminus A$”.

How do you prove that “if $A\subseteq B$, then $C\setminus B\subseteq C\setminus A$”?

You take any $x\in C\setminus B$. This translates into $x\in C$ and $x\notin B$. From $x\notin B$, we can deduce $x\notin A$ (because $A\subseteq B$). Therefore $x\in C$ and $x\notin A$, which translates into $x\in C\setminus A$.

Answer (score 0):

Since you wish to **prove** that $C\setminus B\subseteq C\setminus A$, starting a sentece with “If $C\setminus B\subseteq C\setminus A$…” is useless.

Take $x\in C\setminus B$. Then $x\notin B$. Since $B\supseteq A$, $x\notin A$. On the other hand, $x\in C\setminus B\implies x\in C$. Therefore, $x\in C\setminus A$.

Edit: typo in the last implication

Answer (score 0):

Take $x\in C\setminus B$. Assume that $x\notin C\setminus A$.

It means that $x\notin B$, but $x\in A$.This is a contradiction, because $A\subseteq B$.

So our assumption is wrong.So, $x\in C\setminus A$ must be.